# Auto-Complete da IDE Code::Blocks não exibe os métodos da biblioteca Allegro

Tags: autocompletar, codeblocks, allegro

Eu estou usando o allegro no Code:Blocks, porem quando se trata de algo do Allegro o Code::Blocks não consegue usar o AutoComplete, o que devo fazer para corrigir isso?

Comment: Como você está usando o código/biblioteca? Por um exemplo, talvez seja uma falha em seu código.

Comment: Desculpe, eu não entendi a pergunta.

Comment: Você deve ter importado a API assim om `#include <allegro>` e iniciado ela assim: `int main() { al_init(); }`, estou certo? Se fez isto, significa que você já tem algo pronto, é isto que pedi para adicionar a sua pergunta, um exemplo do seu código que ocorre o problema.

Comment: Ocorre o problema no código todo. por exemplo, caso eu digite "al_in" e aperte ctrl + space deveria aparecer a opção "al_init()", porem não aparece nada.

Comment: A entendi, pensei que o problema fosse com a biblioteca, então o seu problema é com o IDE.